# Can you start an outside process with Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, process

The System.Diagnostics assembly is part of the Silverlight CLR framework, but it only includes classes related to debugging, the Process class is not available. Is there any other way to start an outside process from a Silverlight application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can in Silverlight 4 (in out-of-browser with elevated full trust), example:

```
dynamic cmd = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
cmd.Run("calc.exe", 1, true);
```

Comment: In Silverlight 5 you can realize much more things with Silverlight 5 RC–Platform Invocation. http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/09/05/silverlight-5-rc-platform-invocation.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Using an elevated trust out of browser app (shall we coin ETOOB or OOBET for short) Silverlight 4 application you may be able to start a new app in a new process if it is a COM Automation server.  For example:-

```
dynamic excel = ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
```

Should fire up Excel in its own procress.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your application either in the browser or as a standard out of browser application, being able to start another process would break the Silverlight model, allowing your application access to the machine outside the browser sandbox.

A full trust application will be able to do this.

Why do you want to start another process?

Comment: This might be useful if you are running your app out of browser and want to launch something on the client, I imagine the user would have to grant permission to perform an action like this however.

Comment: @Crackerjack - Out of browser applications are still sandboxed (from what I've read), you might be able to do this with full trust applications in SL4 - but I've not looked at this aspect yet.

Comment: For example if I need to encode the recorded on the client stream before to send it on the server.

Answer (score 2):

There is no short answers, but there is a complex one...

If you are runnign SL4 Out-Of-Browser, and you indicated that you are ok running elivated (which really mean SL doesnt run in IE-Protected mode, but rather as standard app...) there is a way for you by using WMI to basically do ANY THING you want to. This blog post will help you - http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures .
Just keep in mind, this is high end fancy coding, so watch yourself ;)

There are [two great sample chapters](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/preview.html) on Windows Phone and Silverlight for Windows Phone on the [LearningWindosPhone.com](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/) site. There is great Windows [Phone Trainng material](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/WP7TrainingKit/) , and dont forget the [Windows Phone Develoeprs Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/wpdev/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Silverlight inside an ASPX page you could use HtmlDocument.Window.Invoke to call a JavaScript function which could in turn call a static method within your page (using WebMethod attribute)

The [article here](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) describes the JS/ASPX bridge well.

Kindness,

Dan

NB: Not sure I agree with what you are trying to do; just want to help you do it :)