# Open windows calculator from website

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

How can i open windows calculator from website?
with javascript or actionscript?
Ive tried avtiveX but its only in explorer, I want to open calculator from google chrome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422093/run-a-program-from-a-local-webpage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a program from a local webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422093/run-a-program-from-a-local-webpage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't*. Consider the implications if you could open an arbitrary program on someone's computer from a web page...

---

*(* Without writing and installing a plug-in, and plug-ins are increasingly being phased out by browser vendors in favor of sandboxed extensions.)*

Comment: nek minute someone launches ie.. i'll be damned! *jokes*

Answer (score 6):

The only solution i found is using URI scheme

```
window.open('Calculator:///'); /* shows a confirm dialog to run the app*/
```

i'm not sure if this would work on older versions (7,8,8.1) but it works on windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Use href="ms-calculator://" but you'll get a popup asking if you want to open it. If that is no good, then you would have to somehow get it to open without the alert popup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calculator:` URI (just as a URL), it will prompt the user with an html message first.