# How to run windows application from WebPage?

Tags: c#, php, apache

I have a webpage using PHP + apache.

And simple model like this:

How I run a app (write by C#) from my webpage?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a program from a local webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422093/run-a-program-from-a-local-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

As Per an Article [Here](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/09/how-to-execute-local-file-using-html.html) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RunFile() {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
    }
</script>
<a onclick='RunFile();'>NotePad</a>
```

**Solution 2 :**

As Per Microsoft Article,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

You can Run a local application by **Registering an Application to a URI Scheme**.

Comment: Let me see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, I try solution 1. I use full code and save it as extension .html . But it not run. Must I install any thing else?

Comment: If I save it with extension .hta and run it on webserver (apache). I force me download this file and then It run success. How to run directly?, skip download step?