# Open application on local webpage on osx

Tags: javascript, php, html, macos

How would I have a button on a local webpage (running locally on localhost) to open a local application on OSX?

I have looked through some answers for windows but can't figure out how to get it to work on OSX.

[Run a program from a local webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422093/run-a-program-from-a-local-webpage)

Comment: Why do you say you couldn't figure out how to get those to work on OSX. How did you try them? What happened then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using MAMP on my Mac OS X (high sierra), and in PHP the code is :

```
$command = '/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari';
$escaped_cmd = escapeshellcmd($command);
system($escaped_cmd);
```

Have tested this and it does work in opening up the application locally.  You can even call it from the Terminal to test if it works after creating the above code in a .php file.

Example in Terminal on Mas OS X:

```
php theabovecode.php
```

Comment: how would I turn this into a button you click on the page so it runs the code?

Comment: @Matt trying to help. What do you expect to appear on the screen when the button is clicked?

Comment: Just to open the application, i just need to figure out how to integrate this code as i think it works

Comment: Either you can use a hyperlink to load the PHP file containing the above codes, or you can use an HTML form (which the action is the PHP file above) and submit the form. In both ways, the page will be blank unless you have something to output in the PHP file, e.g. output some HTML codes, or print some wordings.

Comment: Also, you may also want to write some mechanisms to check whether the program exists and is launched correctly.