# Launching a desktop application from a browser(client web page)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, protocols

I need to launch an application which is installed in the client machine when the user clicks the link in the client webpage from browser. for instance like launching the Goto meeting application from the client machine when clicking the URL link if installed else providing the download link.

I tried with ActiveXobject approach which works only with IE browser.And also check with FileAPI.

In the following link they mentioned about using Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol Handler. Since I'm new to it. Can you please guide me where to start.

[Launch application from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/launch-application-from-a-browser[1])

About the environment. My server application is in Asp.Net MVC platform.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you mean something like the `mailto:...` which opens the users email editor, then [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/10/19/register-a-custom-url-protocol-handler.aspx) explains the basics of what you need to do. In involves creating a console app and creating an installer that modifies the users registry settings. Then your users will have to download it and install it on their computers (assuming they trust you)

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser prohibits you from executing anything locally I think the best way to solve your problem would be to create Chrome/Firefox extensions.

Extensions are not bound and can be executed locally.