# Open Windows program in a HTML page

Tags: html

Suppose I have a HTML page (which happens to be generated and served by Java EE) that has a button and when pressing this button, I want a Windows application to be run on the local computer ( i.e. Word oder Excel). How do I achieve this? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/launch-application-from-a-browser) but it hasn't worked.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what i was looking for. It fails at the communication between application ( browser ) and windows.

Comment: ahh you are trying to do that from the browser. I doubt that this is possible due to security issues.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Even with an encrypted communication setup? Even if i am only using the application on the server ( LAN) ?

Comment: no i am not sure about that.

Comment: This process is probably not advised at all due to security issues as bwright as mentioned. The only workaround is to use nasty ActiveX or VBScript components for the front end (which is never good) or if the host is local, start a process via the backend code.

Comment: Can you give an example of how such backend code could look like?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is basically possible in java. All you have to do is to put this line of code at your server side like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "open", "/path/to/app/SomeApp.app"} );
```

This'll open the app at the server side. Obviously you'll have to run eclipse (or the IDE you're using) with admin permission to achieve this. 
Is that what you're looking for?