# Use JavaFx into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is it possible to use JavaFx embed into Javascript and open from the browser.

I need to achieve this without using Jnlp into javascript.

Can this be done?

Comment: There is no javaFX embedded in javascript, but there is Javascript embed in JRE+ JavaFX. So i guess the answer is "NO"

Comment: Is there any way to invoke JavaFx from Web browser without Jnlp?

Comment: Applet, but i won't recommend it, I think its support has been removed from chrome. The real solution is to launch it like an application: solutions are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/launch-application-from-a-browser