# Can we open specific desktop app using mailto

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, mailto

Is there any way around to open mailto using specific APP only,

using javascript  or any client side,

e.g:- on :mailto ---- default Outlook APP should open or a web url if there is no APP present

Comment: No. This is determined by the client software. For instance my browser will open gmail and not outlook.

Comment: Are you asking about mobile or desktop? What OS/browser? It makes a difference. For instance, for mobile, there's [Can I make a link that will open in my app if it's installed, and fall back to a different URL if not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710902/215552). For Windows, there's [Open a desktop app by clicking on a link on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57992804/215552)