# How browser open a desktop application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js

I have a task in my job here to open a desktop program to get some info from a device. The desktop application is made by me for get some information from a keypad, the user insert the data and the software get from the COM port for the keypad and register it in a file in system. I don't have any way/software to get this information in browser, and the customer don't have the option to change for a new one because they have a thousands of these keypads.

When I open a new Teams chat from web outlook, he ask for open a the desktop application:

[image]

How this works? I know the xdg-open is a service from linux to open files in system (I using ubuntu, is possible in windows is a different starter).

I only need to know how they made this or what is the protocol to start this windows box to ask if agree to open or not the application from browser.

Comment: See also [How to launch an application from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057576/215552)

Comment: For security reasons browsers just can't do that,..  But if you want to access the com port, you could maybe look at  Web Serial API ,. It's pretty new, but Chrome appears to support it.

Comment: The web Serial Api is my last chose for do this. I have see the ActiveXObject but the developer.mozilla.org says that only work on IE browser. I tried the ActiveXObject but don't wok well. But if I not found any information about how they start this applications from the browser I will be need to make from Web Serial API