# how to RUN downloaded EXE from website like LogMeIn Rescue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

how to Launch EXE required for my website, that suite all browsers, exactly like LogMeIn Rescue **Launch** button functionality, i have tried using **ActiveXObject**, but it working only with IE. your help appreciated.

Comment: You can't run exe from your website. Thankfully.

Comment: @adiga Thanks for your response, wanted to integrate like how LogMeIn Rescue Lunches EXE from downloaded path

Comment: You probably have to install something manually in your system for them to be able to do that

Comment: @adiga, i'm just installing LogMeIn Rescue EXE in my machine, then while i click on Launch button on LogMeIn Rescue Website it Launches EXE.

Comment: [How to launch an application from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576)