# How can i open visual studio code with browser

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

How can I make "visual studio code" open when a button is pressed on my website?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/how-to-launch-an-application-from-a-browser

Comment: @Steve actually yes, you can't launch the application, but when I install visual studio extensions from microsoft (like "Live Share"), after logging in, an option like "Would you like to open visual studio code" appears at the top of the website. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `href` of your button to the text `vscode:` this should bring up dialog in the browser that a website wants to open vscode.

```html
<a href="vscode:">Clicking me will create a prompt to open vscode</a>
```

[image]

**If you want to open vscode without user input you can use the `window.open` method.**

In your case:

```js
window.open("vscode:", "_blank")
```

will create an automatic pop-up to open vscode.

Comment: i create a test code and i wrote:
`
<a href="vscode:">open vscode</a>
`
and nothing happened

Comment: Did you click the link that appeared?

Comment: @mrdenizlp I've made an edit to my post that should hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: it just seemed like the page was being refreshed but visual studio code didn't open
I'm wondering if the problem is with me

Comment: If you already have visual studio opened  nothing will happen. @mrdenizlp

Comment: I closed the program and tried again. Again nothing happened and in the last code you edited, a new tab with the url `vscode:` opened in the browser but again doesn't work

Comment: @mrdenizlp If you create a new tab and type `vscode:` does anything happen, if not try `vscode:extension`

Comment: I'm starting to think that the problem is me. I guess it's because I'm using "VS Code Insiders". I'll write again if I can't find the problem by searching a little more. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a href="vscode://file/path/to/my_project/readme.md">open readme.md in vscode</a>
```

Comment: it doesn't work too, 
I'm wondering if the problem is with me