# How to catch parameters from URL call

Tags: c#, .net, url, registry

I have an application which relies on being called by a custom URL protocol; for reference see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/how-to-launch-an-application-from-a-browser?fbclid=IwAR2RUwtx2YUxB-lGGZIZO85bTevvXACUk4VKdkAQww5bl0HRGrpSJy4IhD8). The registry link works, but when I try to catch passed parameters from the URL (e.g. I launch `customurl://param1=xy&param2=xy` in a browser) I seem to fail it with the code below;

**Program.cs**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    [...]
    Application.Run(new Form1(args));
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public Form1(string[] args) {
    [...]
    if (args.Length > 0) {
        string name = args[0];
        label1.Text = "received paramter: " + name;
    } else {
        label1.Text = "no received parameter!";
    }
}
```

The condition always chooses the else branch, which means the `args[]` array contained none of the passed parameters. What am I doing wrong? Is there another specific method to catch parameters given these conditions?

Comment: Try taking separate variable instead of args array in forms1 method as parameter and make sure your url looks like `customurl?param1=xy&param2=xy`

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo, but you seem to have forgotten to denote the start of the GET query using `?`. Your URL should be `customurl://?param1=xy&param2=xy`

Comment: @ogjtech it was not a typo, but the result is the same unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you observe can be caused by forgetting the `"%1"` in the registry.  `"%1"` is a placeholder for the URL.   If you forget to include it, the URL won't get passed to your handler.

Here is another SE post with similar instructions [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)   It shows you exactly where you need to put the `"%1"`.