# How to open a mobile or desktop app with JavaScript from the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, telegram, whatsapp

How to open a mobile or desktop app with JavaScript from the browser?

A perfect example of what I want to achieve is what Whatsapp and Telegram do when they manage to run their mobile or desktop apps after a click on a website button.

- Whatsapp (A click on ***Continue to Chat*** will open the WhatsApp app);
  [image]
- Telegram (A click on ***VIEW IN TELEGRAM*** will open the Telegram app);
  [image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057617/14577449) answer to a similar question might help you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking

Comment: An application can register itself for a particular protocol. And what happens here is not that the website requests to open a particular application, but an "action" for a particular protocol is requested. And the browser suggests to do that "action" with the application which registered for that protocol.

Comment: There really is no reliable way to do this. It works as @t.niese says, but also depends on the permissions the user have given the apps on their phone. And it probably wont work if the website is visited through an in-app browser, like Facebook tends to do.

Comment: Thank you! @juhuja They talk about a windows specific solution but I am looking for a more generic one.

Comment: @Gnopor You can't open an arbitrary program on client's computer, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows.open(app://,"_blank","location=yes)

Comment: And how exactly is this supposed to be used? This isn't even valid syntax.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
<a href="tg://resolve?domain=my_group_username">Open Telegram group</a>
<script>
  document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      location.href = this.href;
    }
  });
</script>
```

This code creates a link with the URL tg://resolve?domain=my_group_username, which is the URL scheme associated with the Telegram app. When the link is clicked, the Telegram app will be opened and the user will be taken to the specified group.

Note that this code is specific to the Telegram app and will not work for other apps. **Each app has its own custom URL scheme, and you will need to consult the app's documentation to determine what it is and how to use it.**

eg: Open the url such as https://t.me/publictestgroup , then open the devtools, check the Elements, click the 「Select an element in the page to inspect it」, choose View in Telegram, and you can see the flow:

```
<div class="tgme_page_action">
  <a class="tgme_action_button_new shine" href="tg://resolve?domain=publictestgroup">View in Telegram</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the point of that click event handler? Doesn't `location.href = this.href;` basically happen by default?

Comment: And OP is not asking specifically about Telegram or any other specific app.

Comment: On IOS/Android use Deep links, click [Deep links](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10023042?hl=en#zippy=%2Cfor-android-apps---app-links%2Cfor-ios-apps---universal-links%2Cfor-android-or-ios---custom-schemes) check details.

Comment: @gre_gor You are right, My answer is based on PC, and Each APP has different URL scheme, for example, Telegram scheme [Deep Links](https://core.telegram.org/api/links). But on browser we can use : ```<a href="custom URL scheme"></a>```