# How do browsers invoke external applications such as Teams or Zoom from just a URL?

Tags: javascript, browser, microsoft-teams

When I paste an URL generated by Teams into a browser (particularly Chrome), the browser asks me whether to open the link in the browser or in the Teams external application. What is the mechanism behind that makes this possible? Does Teams register some sort of browser extension when installed on my PC? How can I invoke a random application from a browser and pass an URL to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch an application from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/how-to-launch-an-application-from-a-browser)

Comment: @Cjmarkham it would, but I have no `customurl` key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in my registry, yet the browser still can invoke Teams. EDIT: I found this other answer that seems more updated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local application registers a custom [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) with the operating system. So instead of a URI with an `https://` for Web browsing, the app might declare (upon installation) that it can open a `x-custom-protocol://` scheme.

The specifics of how a local app does this vary by platform (Windows, macOS, Android, iOS, etc.) but when the browser encounters 'x-custom-protocol://' that it suspects it can't handle, it offers to open in the external application.

In the Teams case on Windows, when you install Teams it registers `msteams://` as its URI scheme ("protocol handler" to some) and then when the browser encounters an `msteams://` link, it asks if you want to hand it off to the installed Teams app.

Comment: Great! That's the answer I was looking for. I knew it was related with a custom protocol, but I could not figure out how it was registered. Here is the answer for Windows: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows