# How do I make it that a HTML file that can open apps per Button (Spotify, Steam, etc.)

Tags: html, windows, web-applications, windows-11

I wanted to create a HTML file that I can use as my Startpage in my Browser to open apps I need, without making my desktop messy. Better yet not using the desktop at all. Problem is, I don't know what to use or even how to use any method to make that happen. It should be possible, because Spotify will open a Window in the Browser, asking to open the Spotify App. I want to do the same, just for more options.

I googled and didn't find quite what I'm looking for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/how-to-launch-an-application-from-a-browser This question may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Apps</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/" target="blank">Spotify</a> <br/>
<a href="https://store.steampowered.com/mobile/" target="blank">Steam</a> <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most applications have specific URLs associated with them. You can find these URLs by searching online. For example, Spotify's app URL is `spotify:app`

In your HTML file, create buttons or links for each application you want to launch.

Example -

```html
<a href="spotify:app">Open Spotify</a>
<a href="steam://open/">Open Steam</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use App URIs / protocols to solve this. These are like hyperlinks, but instead of bringing you to a webpage it calls functions from applications. One of the most popular examples of this is being able to open the calculator by typing `ms-calculator://`.

Spotify and Steam both support this and also have their own unique protocols too. This example shows the links for opening the apps you selected, and a few other protocols that you can mess around with.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <a href="spotify:app">Spotify</a>
    <a href="spotify:track:TrackIDHere">Favorite Song</a>
    <br>
    <a href="steam://openurl/">Steam</a>
    <a href="steam://store/StoreID">Game Store</a>
    <a href="steam://run/GameID">Run Game</a>
 </html>
```