# how to open local file with its default launching application in silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm using in-browser application with elevated trust. I have local file path (say files in `my documents`) & I want to launch that file in its default application. how to get this working?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2717064/1021555).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you start an outside process with Silverlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586128/can-you-start-an-outside-process-with-silverlight)

Comment: @icebat: the link you have given is about silverlight 4 and it refers to out-of-browser application. Silverlight 5 provides more functionalities for in-browser applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic dynamic_obj = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
dynamic_obj.Run(FilePath);
```

This worked perfectly fine.

Note: It needs to add reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`